# PHP-Composer Running in Windows Compiled in WSL cannot recognize path properly

Tags: php, composer-php, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, this is my setup:

1. I have all codes checked out, composer installed in WSL (aka Linux)
2. The site is then served via laragon on Windows
3. The site sits in a Windows Directory (`/mnt/c/laragon/www` for Linux, `C:\laragon\www` for Windows) that is case-sensitive aware

### Composer.json:

```
"repositories" : {
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./nova-components/UserFix"
        }
},
"require" : {
     "x/userfix" : "*"
}
```

After I ran `composer install` on Linux, I went to Laragon (Windows) to run the site, most stuff works.I got the following error message on Laravel's error display package named Whoops, so I know Laravel and composer is working properly.

Except for these path repositories, it throws such error :

```php
include(C:\laragon\www\koreconx\vendor\composer\.. /x/userfix/src/ToolServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
```

because obviously, Windows and Linux has different PATH Separators, and .. is not recognized as a path in WIndows ... So, how should I fix this ? I don't suppose that I can use `PATH_SEPARATOR` in a json file ...